# AKKA FSM : Messages are not delivered to FSM actor references properly

Tags: scala, akka, actor, fsm

I've a very strange problem with AKKA FSM.
I've a pool of fsm actor references created at the time of app initialization and the requirement is to send incoming streams of messages to all those actors references, so unfortunately some of the messages are not being sent properly.

Is there a mechanism to track the messages are delivered or not, Please let me know if anybody encountered/solved these.

Appreciate your help!

Thanks,
~Shiva

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the [FSM Documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.5/scala/fsm.html), specifically the section on Testing and Debugging Finite State Machines.  In a nutshell, you need to:

- Wrap your receive in a `LoggingFSM`
- Make sure to set the config setting `akka.actor.debug.fsm` to `true`
- Make sure your logging level is set to `DEBUG`,

If you do all of that you should start seeing debug level messages related to events/state transitions/timers for your FSM actors.